# Spring import runs hibernate persistence twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, spring-mvc

I have 2 spring configurations :

```
spring-servlet.xml
spring-security.xml
```

needed to add this line to security:

```
<beans:import resource="spring-servlet.xml"/>
```

Now hibernate is ran twice, this is log screenshot :

[image]

my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `<beans:import resource="spring-servlet.xml"/>`,

and set

```
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml;/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml 
</param-value>
```

and maybe you twice define sessionFactory bean. Remove one of them.

EDIT:

Ok, two context is normal. One - application context, loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`, should contains definition of sessionFactory, dao, services, etc. usually its name is `applicationContext.xml`

DispatcherServlet should contains only beans for MVC. You can define conext name in parameter:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Did this, still same, nope, have only one of them in my configuration.

Comment: So what I must do exactly? the dispatcher autoloads my xml and also contextloaderlistener loads those 2 xmls now, removed imoprt.

Comment: you should decide what beans you need for MVC and put it in sprint-servlet.xml. Rest of beans (Services, DAO, hibernate session factory, tx manager etc) goes to application-context.xml If you're using spring-security, put all security-related things in spring-security.xml. How-to http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part6.html